# Rails / Postgres - Find rows having exactly n associated rows

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-9.1

In my Rails 4 / Postgres 9.1 application, the user is able to tag phrases.  There is a **phrases** table that is associated with the **tags** table through the join table **phrase_tags**, and in the corresponding models, are linked via **has_many :through** associations.

I want the user to be able to search for Phrases that have *all* of the Tags they specify as input.  For example, find Phrases that are tagged with both "objects" and "colors".

I have a working solution that looks like this (in phrase.rb). tags_array is an array of strings:

```
scope :tagged_with_all, -> (tags_array) {
  joins(:tags)
  .where("tags.name in (?)", tags_array)
  .group("phrases.id").having("count(*) = ?", tags_array.count)
}
```

which ActiveRecord converts into:

```
SELECT "phrases".* FROM "phrases" 
INNER JOIN "phrase_tags" ON "phrase_tags"."phrase_id" = "phrases"."id"   
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "phrase_tags"."tag_id" 
WHERE (tags.name in ('objects','colors')) 
GROUP BY phrases.id HAVING count(*) = 1
```

This works fine, the `GROUP BY / HAVING` selects only those phrases that have a number of associated tags equal to the length of tags_array.

The problem is this: when I combine this scope with anything else that has another JOIN, Postgres complains that the primary key of that join table must be included in the GROUP BY clause or aggregated (see example below).  Is there another way to make this work (possibly with a recursive subselect?) that doesn't use GROUP BY?

Example error:  Here I want to get all of the tagged phrases, joined with their translations in a given language:

```
Phrase.joins("LEFT JOIN translations t on t.phrase_id = phrases.id and 
t.language_id = #{lang_id}")
.select("phrases.*, t.id AS translation_id, t.native_text as
translated_text")
.tagged_with_all(tag_items)
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT phrases.*, t.id AS translation_id, t.native_text as translated_text 
FROM "phrases" INNER JOIN "phrase_tags" 
ON "phrase_tags"."phrase_id" = "phrases"."id" 
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "phrase_tags"."tag_id" 
LEFT JOIN translations t on t.phrase_id = phrases.id and t.language_id = 11 
WHERE (tags.name in ('objects','colors')) 
GROUP BY phrases.id HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "t.id"
must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: did you mean to write `HAVING count(*) = 2` since there are 2 tags? also I'm not sure how the query you posted works, because you're selecting * but only group by id, which is not legal in postgres

Comment: can you show the combine result give you an error?

Comment: See edit, Juan Carlos.  Thank you.

Comment: FuzzyTree: yes, the generated HAVING clause is as you indicated (see example in edited question).  My understanding is that using GROUP BY with just the primary key is legal in postgres, but I'm not a postgres expert.